# How to use the \L command in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, errors

While Using the command  `\L` in LaTeX

Error Display:

```
latex error mathcal allowed only in math mode
```

Comment: Do you mean `\L` command?

Comment: [welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/PiJ21) Works [fine](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zXnyyYLz) on my machine. Please provide a [minimal working example](http://goo.gl/5XLQU) unless the problem disappears after you switch to math mode (as suggested by the error message). You may also want to have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You might have a look to [our start page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436): it will help you to familiarize with the site. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

Comment: @NilsL Well, `\L` gives a warning if used in math mode, but it _looks_ fine. In any case, there's nothing happening with mathcal!

Comment: I presume you have a `\renewcommand{\L}{\mathcal{L}}`. Are you using `$\L$` as opposed to simply `\L` ?

Answer (score 8):

The standard command `\L` may not be used in math at all, so will not give the error you show.

I would guess that a local definition in your files has

```
\renewcommand\L{\mathcal{L}}
```

in which case it will generate a curly L in math mode and the error you show if used out of math. To avoid the error use `$\L$` to get back to math mode.

Comment: one of us beat the other by a couple of seconds. :) +1